# PHP two forms, one page

Tags: php, forms, oop, submit

So in school we're learning about OOP in PHP and for our assignment we need to use 2 forms. this is the first time I'm using 2 forms in one page and I've been trying to figure out how to check which form is being submitted and create the according object. 
Apparently, afer looking at some other questions, just using `if (!empty($_POST['SubmitButtonName']))` should work, but it doesnt.
Hope someone can help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong :)

PHP:

```
if (!empty($_POST['sportwgn'])) 
{
    try 
    {
       $sport->Merk = $_POST['merk'];
       $sport->AantalPassagiers = $_POST['AantalPassagiers'];
       $sport->AantalDeuren = $_POST['AantalDeuren'];
       $sport->Stereo = isset($_POST['stereo']) ? true : false;
       $sport->Save();
       $succes= "Uw sportwagen is gereserveerd!";
    }
    catch( Exception $e)
    {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
if (!empty($_POST['vrachtwgn'])) 
{
    try 
    {
       $vracht->Merk = $_POST['merk'];
       $vracht->AantalPassagiers = $_POST['AantalPassagiers'];
       $vracht->AantalDeuren = $_POST['AantalDeuren'];
       $vracht->MaxLast = $_POST['MaxLast'];
       $vracht->Save();
       $succes= "Uw vrachtwagen is gereserveerd!";
    }
    catch( Exception $e)
    {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Forms:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        <label for="merk">merk</label>
        <input type="text" id="merk" name="merk">
        <br>
        <label for="AantalPassagiers">Aantal passagiers</label>
        <input type="number" min="2" max="4" id="AantalPassagiers" name="AantalPassagiers">
        <br>
        <label for="AantalDeuren">Aantal deuren</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="AantalDeuren" name="AantalDeuren">
        <br>
        <label for="stereo">Stereo?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="stereo" id="stereo" value="stereo"><br>
        <br></div><div class="box">
        <button type="submit" name="sportwgn">Reserveer</button></div>
    </form>

</div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<h1 class="box">Reserveer een Vrachtwagen!</h1>
<div id="content">

    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="merk">merk</label>
        <input type="text" id="merk" name="merk">
        <br>
        <label for="AantalPassagiers">Aantal passagiers</label>
        <input type="number" min="2" max="4" id="AantalPassagiers" name="AantalPassagiers">
        <br>
        <label for="AantalDeuren">Aantal deuren</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="AantalDeuren" name="AantalDeuren">
        <br>
        <label for="MaxLast">Max last</label>
        <input type="number" min="1" max="5" id="MaxLast" name="MaxLast"><br>
        <br></div><div class="box">
        <button type="submit" name="vrachtwgn">Reserveer</button></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You can add hidden field for every form and check is this field exists in $_POST array than you know which form was send;

Comment: What exactly isn't working. Which line is it getting to. I assume in the real code you have the closing tag on the second form

Comment: if(isset($_POST['sportwgn'])){

Comment: @Zaki I'll try doing that.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Yes in the real code I have the closing tag. the problem is that the form's don't seem to submit. I had the first form and the first If-statement working. But I have to add the second form and and I need a different if-statement for it, so i'm trying to figure out how to make sure the second form doesn't use the first 'If' (that's why I'm was trying to use the button names if the !empty($_POST['SubmitButtonName'])).
If that makes sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your forms post on the same page (...action=""...) divide your code in php side to two actions by the submit button.
for the forms with

```
<button type="submit" name="sportwgn">Reserveer</button></div>
```

use

```
if(isset($_POST['sportwgn'])) {
// your code
}
```

and for

```
<button type="submit" name="vrachtwgn">Reserveer</button></div>
```

use

```
if(isset($_POST['vrachtwgn'])) {
// your code
}
```

Comment: This worked, should've probably thought about that haha, but thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if(isset($_POST['buttonName']))` to check if it's in the post values.

Answer (score 0):

Use `action` attribute to submit forms to different destinations.

```
<form action="firstForm.php" method="post">
...
</form>

<form action="secondForm.php" method="post">
...
</form>
```

And create 2 files for handling form posting.